# Browser 200 (cached) force reload

Tags: c#, .net, angularjs, google-chrome, caching

I am developing a AngularJs 1.3.7 front-end app with a C# back-end API. Just recently added caching to server side which now causes a headache. Since the Get requests sets the cache-control header the browser after performing a request once, caches the API response. After data was cached the back-end correctly invalidates the cache after any POST/PUT/DELETE request was made to the servers controller. The problem is that the browser (in my case Chrome) only refreshes the cache if the request (POST/PUT/DELETE) was made to the same URL.

---

Working example sequence: GET www.bestGames.com/games -> POST www.bestGames.com/games -> GET www.bestGames.com/games (the cache was cleared and the data was re-updated correctly).

Not-working: GET www.bestGames.com/games -> PUT www.bestGames.com/games/20 -> GET www.bestGames.com/games (not updating cache, showing old data).

Not-working: GET www.bestGames.com/games -> PUT www.bestGames.com/games?id=20 -> GET www.bestGames.com/games (not updating cache, showing old data).

Working: GET www.bestGames.com/games -> PUT www.bestGames.com/games -> GET www.bestGames.com/games (the cache was cleared and the data was re-updated correctly).

So, is there no other way to refresh browser cache other than:

- Adding something like "?=random" to GET request
- Adding an extra request to www.bestGames.com/games just to clear the browser cache.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this answer can help you. https://superuser.com/questions/89809/how-to-force-refresh-without-cache-in-google-chrome

Dependant on OS, but I assume windows since you're using C#. Try ctrl F5 or shift F5 to reload while ignoring cache.

Comment: I need more of a coded solution. And I do not need to clear the whole cache only of a specific URL.